# iOS collectionView Cell for reuse.why backgroundColor for cell is well, when i add badge, appear badge bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: calendar.gif]

this is my @{eventTime:eventCount}:

LYQMemoVC.m:196 dic :{
    "2019-01-12" : "2",
    "2019-02-20" : "1",
    "2019-01-13" : "1",
    "2019-02-10" : "1",
    "2019-01-14" : "1"
}

issue:
event not 2019-02-09,but cell have badge...  as this the same location will have badge. not event but appear badge.

the backgroundColor for cell is well, but the badge bug.

(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

```
NSString *identifier = [self.cellDic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath]];

if (identifier == nil) {
    identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALCalendarCell%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath]];
    [_cellDic setValue:identifier forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath]];

    [self registerClass:[ALCalendarCell class]  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
    ALCalendarCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.weekDay = self.titles[indexPath.row];
} else {
    ALCalendarDate *date = self.dates[indexPath.row];
    cell.date = date;


    NSString *dateString;
    if (date.isLastMonth) { 
        dateString = [[ALCalendarHelper lastYearAndMonth:self.yearAndMonth] stringByAppendingFormat:@"-%02zd",date.date.integerValue];
    } else if (date.isNextMonth) { 
        dateString = [[ALCalendarHelper nextYearAndMonth:self.yearAndMonth] stringByAppendingFormat:@"-%02zd",date.date.integerValue];
    } else { 
        dateString = [self.yearAndMonth stringByAppendingFormat:@"-%02zd",date.date.integerValue];
    }

if ([self.config.heightlightDates containsObject:dateString]) {
            cell.backgroundColor = self.config.hl_backgroundColor;
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = self.config.hl_backgroundCornerRadius.floatValue;
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = self.config.hl_textColor;
            [self.config.eventDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                if ([key isEqualToString:dateString]) {
                    cell.badge.badgeValue = [obj intValue];
                    cell.badge.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                    cell.badge.hidden = NO;
                }
            }];
        }
        if ([self.config.selectedDates containsObject:dateString]) {
            cell.backgroundColor = self.config.sel_backgroundColor;
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = self.config.sel_backgroundCornerRadius.floatValue;
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = self.config.sel_textColor;
            [self.config.eventDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                if ([key isEqualToString:dateString]) {
                    cell.badge.badgeValue = [obj intValue];
                    cell.badge.backgroundColor = Config_Main_Color;
                    cell.badge.hidden = NO;
                }
            }];
        }
}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: From your post, we can hardly understand what your question is. Plus, we cannot help with the code shown like this. Please post the relevant code as text, not screenshot.

Comment: this is code as text.please help.

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: Probably you don't correctly prepare the cells correctly for reuse

Comment: you can see the eventDic, if calendar.heightlightDates contains eventDic.key, the calendar.cell has a badge.  2019-02-09 no event,  but calendar cell badge is 2, and 2019-03 as same as location already has badge ....

Comment: if you notice , backgroundColor and textColor is well, bug i dic enum, the badge appear issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your badge is persistent across cell 're-uses'.
You want to hide and show the badge according to the date.

In your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function you check for the following:

```c
if ([key isEqualToString:dateString]) {
  cell.badge.badgeValue = [obj intValue];
  cell.badge.backgroundColor = Config_Main_Color;
  cell.badge.hidden = NO;
}
```

and the last line un-hides your `cell.badge`. You never actually **hide** your badge again. And since you're reusing cells, there is **no default value**.

Your code should probably look somewhat like the following (copy to both if-statements):

```c
if ([key isEqualToString:dateString]) {
  cell.badge.badgeValue = [obj intValue];
  cell.badge.backgroundColor = Config_Main_Color;
  cell.badge.hidden = NO;
}
else {
  cell.badge.badgeValue = 0;
  cell.badge.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: is there a reason why you are managing all of the cell's properties in the view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method instead of the cell ifself? This is not a very good approach, because only the cell should know what to do with its own properties (you give the cell the number, then it is the cell that decides what to do with it - show a badge, play a sound or perhaps shout out "TWENTY-FOUR!"). For instance, if in the future you need to use the same cell in another view controller, you shouldn't need to rewrite all of that code - which is what you'll need to do with your approach.

Anyway, apparently you are not resetting the cell's badge value in its `prepareForReuse` method.

Try implementing it this way (in the cell's .m file):

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.badge.badgeValue = 0;
}
```